# Java Setup throws NullPointerException in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, java

I need to install Java on a Windows 8.1 virtual machine. This is done by using Hyper-V to access the computer and then using Explorer to download both the Java x64 and i586. When the setup is almost finished I get 2 exceptions that says `NullPointerException` and then Unable to launch the application? The setup says that the installation is success but when visiting the after installation java webpage it says Check that you got the recommended version of Java for your operating system.

Windows 8.1
Java file 1 : jre-8wu31-windows-x64.com
Java file 2 : jre-8wu31-windows-i586.com

I have turned off the antivirus program.

Edit stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.deplay.config.JREInfo.ValidateHomeJRE_int(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deplay.config.JREInfo.initialize(Unknonwn Source)
at com.sun.deplay.config.ClientConfig.refreshProperties(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deplay.config.ClientConfig.init(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deplay.config.WebStartConfig.init(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deplay.config.ClientConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: @Dj. I have added the stracktrace to the post.

Comment: Has Java been install on this VM at any point?  Are you sure the extensions of these files are .com files that seems extremly odd.

Comment: I am a fan of [JavaRA](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) to solve Java installation problems or conflicts.  It will uninstall every trace of Java then offer you to download Java and install it.